# Rxjs Combine multiple observables to a single boolean observable

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am trying to Combine multiple observables to a single boolean observable.

Currently I'm using scan and it's running using the previously emitted value for the accumulator when I need it to use true every time. I'm not sure how to achieve this.

```js
    this.partnershipFundInvalid$ = merge(
      this.partnershipFundId$.pipe(map(id => id === null)),
      this.partnershipsFileUploader.dataImportState$.pipe(map(state => state.file !== null)),
    ).pipe(
      scan((acc, val) => {
        return acc && val === true;
      }, true),
    );
```

Comment: It doesn't sound like you need `scan`. Could you just use `map(val => val === true)`?

Comment: @SteveHolgado map doesnt emit until all the streams are closed

Comment: You are using `merge` so piping through `map` should run on each emission...

Comment: you need takeLast(10) to use map the way you are describing. You are not being helpful

Comment: This question clearly needs more details in the form of expected versus actual output, so voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

#### Scan, but ignore the accumulated value

```ts
    this.partnershipFundInvalid$ = merge(
      this.partnershipFundId$.pipe(map(id => id === null)),
      this.partnershipsFileUploader.dataImportState$.pipe(map(state => state.file !== null)),
    ).pipe(
      scan((acc, val) => {
        return true && val === true; // Replaced acc with "true"
      }, true),
    );
```

#### That's semantically the same as map

```ts
    this.partnershipFundInvalid$ = merge(
      this.partnershipFundId$.pipe(map(id => id === null)),
      this.partnershipsFileUploader.dataImportState$.pipe(map(state => state.file !== null)),
    ).pipe(
      map(val => {
        return true && val === true;
      }),
    );
```

---

> map doesn't emit until all the streams are closed

That's not how map works, it doesn't deal with error or completion emissions.

---

I would suggest updating your question to include what you're trying to accomplish as *'I am trying to "reduce" a Boolean'* is ambiguous. There are many ways to *"reduce" a Boolean*

Comment: thanks, but it will only use the last observable from the merge, think about it like summing booleans

Answer (score 0):

A friend suggested this, i was completely over thinking it.

```js
this.partnershipFundInvalid$ = combineLatest(
  this.partnershipFundId$,
  this.partnershipsFileUploader.dataImportState$,
).pipe(
  map(([fundId, partnershipsFile]) => {
    return fundId == null && partnershipsFile.file !== null;
  }),
);
```

Comment: Why do you use switchMap when you do not neet it? Use CombineLatest + map. Code will bE more readable and will do less.

Comment: If i do that i will get an error `TS2322: Type 'Observable<Observable<boolean>>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<boolean>'.   Type 'Observable<boolean>' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.`
I need to return a new observable

Comment: Do not use "of" operator and return directly fundId == null && partnershipsFile.file !== null

Comment: I didnt even notice i had 'of' in there ‍♂️
thanks mate